# Swageer js doc does not instant update api docs on changes?

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, nodemon

I am using [swagger-jsdoc](https://github.com/Surnet/swagger-jsdoc/blob/master/docs/GETTING-STARTED.md)

I have setup swagger js docs like below in my app.js

```
//include swagger js doc
var swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const pathToSwaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-dist').absolutePath()



const swaggerDefinition = {
    swagger: '2.0',
    info: {
        // API informations (required)
        title: 'API', // Title (required)
        version: '1.0.0', // Version (required)
        description: 'Used for  api documentation', // Description (optional)
    },
    host: `localhost:3000`, // Host (optional)
    basePath: '/app/v1', // Base path (optional)
};


// Options for the swagger docs
const options = {
    // Import swaggerDefinitions
    swaggerDefinition,
    // Path to the API docs
    // Note that this path is relative to the current directory from which the Node.js is ran, not the application itself.
    apis: ['./app/v1/docs/*.yaml']
};

// Initialize swagger-jsdoc -> returns validated swagger spec in json format
const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);

app.use('/v1/docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));
```

I have certain yaml files which  i have written for document the api. I hit the url from browser

```
localhost:3000/v1/docs
```

This shows me documented api in swagger ui. But when i make update in any of the yaml files and refresh the page then i don't see updated changes. I have to stop the `nodemon` process and restart the process again which i do not want to do. So let me know how can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

By default, nodemon looks for files with the .js, .mjs, .coffee, .litcoffee, and .json extensions.

To add other extensions please use the following command:
    nodemon -e yaml

For more details, refer to the official docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon